# Getting error with override get command, when using sibling calls

Tags: cypress

Good day.
Having error :

```
The command that returned the promise was:

  > cy.contains()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > cy.fixture()
```

when using overridden `get` method with sibling contains.

Override command code:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('get', (originalFn, selector, options) => {
    cy.fixture('selectors').then((selectorsJson) => {
        if (selectorsJson.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
            return originalFn(selectorsJson[selector], options)
        }
        return originalFn(selector, options)
    })
})
```

Usage sample:

```js
cy.get("selectorKey").contains('Some text').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have found a workaround, but it requires to have additional logic in each required tests. (In case of sample override get command, it might not been required).

My solution:

**Command:**

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('get', (originalFn, selector, options) => {
    if (options.hasOwnProperty("selectors") && options.selectors.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
        return originalFn(options.selectors[selector], options)
    }
    return originalFn(selector, options)
})
```

**In tests:**

```js
 beforeEach(function() {
        cy.fixture('selectors').as('selectorsJson');
 })

it('Description', function() {
        cy.visit('/some-url');

        cy.get("someSelectorAlias", {selectors: this.selectorsJson}).contains('Some text').click()
});
```

** And also a more simple solution (without get override): **

```js
  beforeEach(function() {
        cy.fixture('selectors').as('selectors');
    })
  it('Some tests', function() {
      cy.visit('/someurl');        
cy.get(this.selectors.someKey).should('be.visible').contains('SomeText')
})
```

Comment: But is maybe there is a better way to not require usage `beforeEach` in each test file. As also ability to output in Command log name of selector key, rather than full selector path?